# Setting a maximum number of replacements for sample with numpy choice

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to select a random sample from an array with a maximum number of replacements.

Take the following example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(3)

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=3)
rng.choice(a, 5)
```

This generates an array of `[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.
Here, the element `0` has been selected four times.
Is there a way to limit this to e.g. two times?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in method to do that, but as long as the numbers are not too big, you can use

```
rng.choice(a.repeat(2), 5, replace=False)
```

to simulate that. But note that if `a` or the number of repetitions is large, this is very inefficient. In that situation it would make sense to write your custom function.

(check out the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice))

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to use the limitation what you would like.
You can choose from them depending your need.

If you measure the performance of the method you chose, you get:

```
a = np.arange(3)                                                                                                                                                                          
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=3)                                                                                                                                                        
timeit l=rng.choice(a, 5)                                                                                                                                                                  
17.2 µs ± 334 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

If you want to allow to use each value maximum two times, it will not make it faster using the same method:

```
a = np.arange(3).repeat(2)                                                                                                                                                           
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=3)                                                                                                                                                   
timeit l=rng.choice(a, 5)                                                                                                                                                                  
17.3 µs ± 359 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

You can however use an own function to achieve must faster execution:

```
import random

def choice(a, n, l):
    choices=[]
    if len(a)*l<n:
        raise ValueError("Impossible")
    s={k:n for k in a}
    for _ in range(n):
        r=random.choice(list(s))
        choices.append(r)
        s[r]-=1
        if s[r]==0:
            del(s[r])
    return choices

random.seed(3)                                                                                                                                                                            
timeit l=choice(range(3), 5, 2)                                                                                                                                                           
3.71 µs ± 22.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

If you need `numpy array` result, you can convert it, loosing a little time, but still being fast enough.

Comment: You non-array solution is faster for small `n` and `l`, but `numpy` `choice` scales better.